# Linked List Alphabetization (Ordered Insertion) Problems in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, nodes, insertion-sort

I am attempting to write a program that will read input from a text file, parse the information, put it into nodes of a linked list, and then allow you to input keywords and get answers from the list.

I have written a function below that is supposed to do sorted insertion, and insert into the list depending upon alphabetical order.

Currently, when I run this program on this text:

ZEEKS, BOB

GOYLE, FRANK

BROWN, JAMES

SMITH, BILL

EARL, JOE

I get this output of last names:

BROWN

EARL

SMITH

GOYLE

ZEEKS

Here is the function I use to try to do the alphabetized insertion:

```
nodeType *insertNodeNewTest(nodeType *head, nodeType *newNode)
{
nodeType *temp = NULL;

temp = head;
nodeType *prev = NULL;

if(head == NULL)
{
    newNode->next = NULL;
    head = newNode;

    return head;
}

else if(strcmp(newNode->lastname, temp->lastname) < 0)  //this
{
    puts("car");

    newNode->next = temp;
//  newNode = head;

    head = newNode;

    return head;
}
else
{

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;

        if(prev == NULL)
        {
            printf("prev null");
        }

        if(strcmp(newNode->lastname, prev->lastname) > 0)
        {

             prev->next = newNode;
             newNode->next = temp;

             return head;
        }
    }
}

temp->next = newNode;
newNode->next = NULL;

return head;

}
```

I was pretty sure I took care of all the cases of insertion (first, middle, last), so I think the problem is somewhere in the changing of variable names, perhaps in the while loop? What's going on, exactly?

I would greatly appreciate any help you guys can give!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. When presenting code, it is a good idea to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) -- two names and links for the same idea.  You've shown one key function; you've not shown the structure definition, nor the outline code that populates the list.  That doesn't (probably shouldn't) be your file-reading code; you can create an array of nodes preinitialized with the names.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jonathan! Sorry for not doing a better job of familiarizing myself with the rules here; I'll be sure to read the links you have provided for me.